# Asp.net Webpage src linking in Dev vs IIS deployed environment

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Ive been developing a web application (asp.net mvc) in VS 2012 and its been running along swimmingly. I have now gone to deploy it to my computers IIS just to run some tests outside VS and Ive come up with some issues.

The issues relate to how images and JS files are linked to. The simplest example of the problem is an image src. So in my site.css I have the following style:

```
.menu_div .mnuHeader
{  
     background: url('/img/menuSectionHeader.png') repeat-x center;     
 }
```

This works fine in the development environment because the VS IIS express instance spins it up as "http://localhost:51034/". But when I have it deployed to IIS the website is located in a virtual directory so the website is referenced as "http://localhost:80/MyWebsite/".

So unless I go through my entire application and change it to /MyWebsite/ than images and resource links will not work (This isnt really feasible as I will have to have two different instances of the application, one for dev and one for deployment, a bit dangerous for just links).

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try relative paths? If CSS file is in /css/ and graphics are in /img/, then your example will be:

```
.menu_div .mnuHeader
{  
     background: url('../img/menuSectionHeader.png') repeat-x center;     
 }
```

You can also try to rewrite /img/ for /MyWebsite/img/ on production: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: This is the proper solution.  Just know that all paths in your CSS file are relative to the CSS file itself.  But any time you start a path with a slash, you are essentially defining an absolute path... which starts at the root.